# Reserve file for ajax request only

Tags: php, ajax, security

I have a massive of scripts that my core application

```
    include('JS/gramp.php');
    include('JS/est.php');
    include('JS/curest.php');
    include('JS/memomarker.php');
    include('JS/local----------.php');
    include('JS/poirel.php');
    include('JS/maplayers.php');
    include('JS/trafficinc.php');
    include('JS/plannedtraffic.php');
    include('JS/transportissues.php');
    include('JS/cams_traff.php');
    include('JS/places2.php');
```

Now these are all being moved to a on the fly loading,  to reduce the size of the application on load

```
if(button_case_curtime==true){
        $(".jsstm").load("<?php echo $core_dir; ?>JS/curresttime.php?la=<?php echo $caseset['iplat']; ?>&lo=<?php echo $caseset['iplong']; ?>&h=<?php echo $days_h; ?>");
        rendermap = true;
        }
```

**issue!** the application requires these files to be secure,  the data involved requires that no one can access.

The ONLY file that will ever request these files will be **index.php**

Any input or idears would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to provide a file to the browser without also providing it to a user.

You could configure your server to only supply the files given an extra HTTP header (which you could add with JS), but nothing would stop people from sending that header manually or just digging the source out of the browser's debugging tools.

Any user you give the files to will have access to the files. If you want to limit which users have access to them, then you have to use auth/authz (which you'll want to apply to the index.php file as well so that unauthorised users don't just get JS errors or silent failure states).

Comment: @Quentin Cheers.  We have a login script.  and the users needs to be logged in for each ajax script to run.

Comment: @Quentin how secure would using a UID generated before the ajax,  storing it as a session. with a 20 second time out be.

Comment: About as secure, but much more complicated, than looking to see if the session says the user is logged in when the JavaScript is request.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you are trying to do is not possible. Ajax requests are not special. They are just HTTP requests. End points created for Ajax should be secured with authentication/authorization just like any other HTTP request end point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial solution that will solve your problem half-way. Request them via a POST request, like so:

```
$.post('JS/maplayers.php', {'ajax':true}, function(){});
```

Notice the POST variable 'ajax'. In the file maplayers.php, add to the beginning the following code:

```
if((!isset($_POST['ajax']))) {
       die('Invalid request, only ajax requests are permitted');
   }
```

Comment: This is trivial for anyone to work around and will break caching.

Comment: No it's not trivial for anyone to work around, it's trivial for programmers to work around. And the author will decide if this is good enough for his use.

Comment: It's trivial for anyone likely to want to look at the JS in the first place to work around.

Comment: Jesus, fine, it's trivial. There, i updated my answer to say so.

Comment: @3Nex thanks,  I looked at this to start with.  The issue with this,  is the data is to sensitive.  I would rather have a slower application than a less secure.